# How to restrict products with 0 stock

Tags: php, stock

I woyld like to know how to restrict products without stock. So not being able to purchase.

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id); //se busca el producto 
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;//Se verifica la sesión por si hay un carro en existencia
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);//Se construye el carro de compras a partir de uno existente, de ser el caso
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);//Se añade el nuevo producto
    $product-> quantity = $product-> quantity-1; //Se resta una unidad al producto seleccionado
    $product->save(); //Se guarda el cambio realizado en la cantidad del producto

    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);//se almacenan los datos en la sesión
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
}
```

Comment: You must query the stock table before allowing them to put the item in their cart.